# Anchored DataGridViews not expanding as expected on installation on other computers

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, datagridview, splitcontainer

I'm working on an C# WinForms App in Visual Studio 2022.

Part of the application is a user control that has several nested SplitContainers which in turn contain either a DataGridView that is docked to fill the entire Panel (which seems to be working fine) or Label with a DataGridView below it, anchored to all sizes.  The idea is to resize the DataGridView when the application is resized but keep the Label static and visible.  While developing the application this worked as I expected, however when run on some of my coworkers computers it does not and leaves empty space at the bottom of the panel.

The application is published with the following configuration:

- Target framework : net6.0-windows
- Deployment mode : Self-contained
- Target runtime: win-x86

User control in design:[user control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g11wj.jpg)

When working: [example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUmQX.jpg)

When not working [example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjSoc.jpg)

As this has been showing up inconsistently across computers that it runs on I suspect that my issue is in how it is published or there is some setting I'm missing on the controls themselves.  I can provide any additional information on request if I've missed something pertinent.

Update:
I've added an app manifest to the project and added:

```
  <application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <windowsSettings>
      <dpiAware xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>
      <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">PerMonitorV2</dpiAwareness>
    </windowsSettings>
  </application>
```

After that didn't work I removed the manifest and updated the csproj file:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <ApplicationHighDpiMode>PerMonitorV2</ApplicationHighDpiMode>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Behavior remains the same.

Comment: Looking at the images you have posted (at 100% scale in the Browser), it appears that the rendering of the non-working version is considerably less sharp. This usually happens when you have a non-DpiAware app. But you said that this is a .Net 6 app (not clear why it's targeting x86), which is DpiAware by default (though it could be simply SystemAware, instead of PerMonitorV2 aware) -- Is the screen of the dev machine scaled, or are you designing at 100% scale? What is the actual DpiAwareness configuration? What is the screen scale of the machines where the UI *misbehaves*?

Comment: Did you port a previously existing application to .Net 6, hence - possibly - not calling the `ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();` method of the default template? So, is there a chance that the app is not actually DpiAware (thus subject to *virtualization*)?

Comment: The application is not a port - the image of the misbehaving screenshot was a coworker testing the application so its possible the difference in sharpness is due to the transmission of the image.  I will however look into checking that the application is actually using the proper DPI Awareness setting.

Comment: That has nothing to do with a .Net 5+ app. Not even a .Net Framework 4.8 app, where you use app.config for that -- In a .Net 6+ app, you call `Application.SetHighDpiMode()` (e.g., `Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.PerMonitorV2);`) in Program.cs. The .Net 6+ templates automatically add a call to `ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize()`, which takes care of this. You can override the default value set by this method, adding, e.g., `<ApplicationHighDpiMode>PerMonitorV2</ApplicationHighDpiMode>` to the Project file (`[Your app name].csproj`)